# How to access the file outside the reader.onload FileReader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filereader

Is there a way where I can access the output inside of reader.onload?

Here is my code:

```
handleFileUpload() {
     this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
     const reader = new FileReader();
     let filtersProduct = [];

     reader.onload = function() {
          let seperate;
          seperate = reader.result.split('\n');
          filtersProduct = seperate;

     }

     reader.readAsText(this.file);
     console.log(filtersProduct);

}
```

But when I try to print it to console, the array is empty.
Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can access outside of the reader.

this code is **synchronous**. it sets callback function then passed and logs console.log even onload function isnt fired.

you should write **asynchronous** code.